# Boot from USB fail, Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, boot, live-usb, unetbootin

I created a live USB of windows 7 with unetbootin.  I'm running Ubuntu 12.04.  I have a Lenovo z580 intel core i7 with 8gb ram.  My computer won't boot from USB.  USB is first in the boot order.  My stick is flagged as boot in gparted.  I tried booting from usb via system setup from the grub menu.  It just sends me back to grub.  BTW the usb stick is formatted fat32 (as per a recommendation that unetbootin will fail with NTFS)  however I also tried with it formatted to NTFS and it also fails to boot from USB.

Answer (score 0):

I think your USB MBR (Master Boot Record) has corrupted. Open Terminal and type these commands:

`sudo apt-get install mbr`
`sudo fdisk -l` (to find out which device is your flash drive)
`sudo install-mbr /dev/sdx` (replacing x with your flash device)

If you see: `install-mbr:/dev/sdc: No boot signature found.  Use --force to override.` Then try:

`sudo install-mbr /dev/sdx --force`

and then create the live USB again.